# How to get Maven to do only my custom profile?

Tags: maven

I have Maven configured with a custom profile to run my Spring Boot application. Most of the time I want to build and run my project. I do so like this: `mvn clean install -Drun`. But sometimes when testing things out I just want to re-run without rebuilding the project. I'd like to do something like `mvn -Drun` but Maven complains that no goals have been specified.

How can I get Maven to execute my custom profile without rebuilding, repackaging, etc?

p.s. I'm running Apache Maven 3.3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how Maven works.

You cannot "run" a profile. A profile is just a part of the POM that you can switch on and off.

You can run single Maven plugin goals (like `dependency:list`). They will pick up their configuration from the POM, possibly from a profile.

Alternatively, you can run phases (i.e. a lifecycle up to a given phase, like when you call `mvn install` it runs the standard lifecycle up to the phase `install`).

Comment: `mvn dependency:list -Drun` doesn't "run" my profile. `mvn install -Drun` DOES run my profile, but also does more than I need given no code has changed. What is the quickest executing Maven command that will get my profile "running" in the shortest amount of time?

Comment: You can look up all goals that are included in your profile and run them from the command line (like when you run a goal `restart` from a plugin `a`, add `a:restart` to the `mvn` call). If you activate the profile, you can read their configuration from the POM.

Comment: Note that with Maven you either run a phase - then Maven starts from the very beginning. Or you run an individual goal. Profiles, on the contrary, are used to enrich the POM. If you activate a profile named "run", Maven will first mix everything from the profile into your POM, and then run whatever you asked it to run. In the moment that a phase or goal starts, Maven has completely forgotten about profiles and cannot tell what was originally inside a profile and what is not. It is like making a dough with flour, mixing all the ingredients and then try to bake only the flour.